# Using VBA for Word, how do I create a range of table cells?

Tags: vba, ms-word, range, cell

I'm trying to learn how to handle Range objects in Word VBA with regards to MS Word tables.

Using the [Range object help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171380%28office.11%29.aspx), it would seem I can create a range of cells as long as the cells are contiguous, however I cannot seem to get the syntax for specifying the Start and End points of the range using cells.

For example:

```
Set rngCells = myTable.Range(Start:=<cell>, End:=<cell>)
```

I'm not sure what to put in for  to indicate the cell to start or the cell to end with. Can someone give me a clue? :)

Edit: I've already created the table from scratch -- I'm trying to use a range of cells for some of the rows in the middle to apply formatting to them. In particular, I'm trying to see if this can be done without using Selection.

Comment: Do you want to create the entire table from scratch? Or just some lines/rows? Or do you even just want to alter the content of existing cells? Please specify, then I might help you. Regards

Comment: Eventually, I'll be doing both -- creating a table from scratch and formatting it; and modifying existing tables' formatting and content. I'm really curious if/how this can be done using ranges as opposed to selections, since you can have multiple ranges but only one selection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for:

```
Set myCells = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, _
             End:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.End)
```

I did not realize the Range object was from the Document object, not the Table object.